# JQuery POST returns status code 200, but Django is not creating object

Tags: jquery, django, api, post

I'm trying to send a POST request to my Django server. I'm using JQuery in this way:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/API/send_news',
        data: {
            newstitle: "randomname"
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.result === 'OK') {
                return HttpResponse("Done")
            } else {
                return HttpResponse("Fail")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I cannot send post request to my funcions due to 403 status code.

Comment: `200` is not an error, is an `status code` the title is wrong. 
You have to say: *Jquery POST returns status code 200, but Django is not creating object*

Comment: Thank you! you are right

Comment: Do you get some error in your terminal once you execute `New.objects.create` ? @Dev9977

Comment: No, i'm also creating order from the Django administration, and i can add object without problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you paste the `New` objcet model code? and step by step, is the json request entering to the `send_news` method?

Comment: I cannot understend your request : "is the json request entering to the send_news method?".
For the model code i update my post. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you add something like: `print 'Entering to this method'` or `print `Line after save` something like that, only to check if the ajax request is accesing to your Django method, or is something wrong with the ajax call

Comment: Ok, its not accessing my method.. how can i solve? thank you!

Comment: Awesome! That is a great point!, now we can debug. Can you paste the routes that you have defined?

Comment: @MrMins thanks for your answer. I tryied to return or print something above in my API (in views.py) and i figured out that nothing is happening. I think that my POST request is not reaching my API function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: to debug this issue, you have to know if your path is the right.
can you add your `urls.py` file?

Comment: @MrMins Ok thank you. I update my post.

Comment: Did you tried in you `ajax: using `url: '/send_news',` ??? 
Add your `urls.py` file too, that is a route problem

Comment: i tried with the new url but still nothing happens...however, changing the url doesnt change the log in the bash or in the crhome console... strange?

Comment: I updated the answer, if you get some errors in your terminal, please, paste them

Comment: Ok tried and just pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `type` to `method: post`, see below:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/API/send_news',
        data: { name: "randomname" },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.result === 'OK') {
                return HttpResponse("Done")
            } else {
                return HttpResponse("Fail")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try 
[Tutorial 3: Class-based Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#using-generic-class-based-views)

If your `URL` in your Ajax method is ok, that should work.

```
class send_news(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):


        news_title = get_param(request.POST, "newstitle", NOT_NONE)
        news_small_description = get_param(request.POST, "newssmalldescription", OPTIONAL)
        news_description = get_param(request.POST, "newsdescription", OPTIONAL)
        news_image = get_param(request.POST, "newsimage", OPTIONAL)

        New.objects.create(
            news_title = newstitle,
            news_small_description = newssmalldescription,
            news_description = newsdescription,
            news_image = newsimage,
        )

        return HttpResponse()
```

And for your `url` file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^send_news', views.send_news, name='send_news'),
]
```

And your `javascript` file:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : {% url 'send_news' %},
        data: {
            newstitle: "randomname",
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.result === 'OK') {
                return HttpResponse("Done")
            } else {
                return HttpResponse("Fail")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: tryied with the new url but its not working.. (you are very kind thanks for your help.)

Comment: Ok tried this also but i get same log: 
`
[15/Jun/2018 23:25:07] "POST /API/invia_news HTTP/1.1" 200 3051
[15/Jun/2018 23:25:07] "GET /static/js/index.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 `

Comment: That is from your browser console, I mean, the log from your terminal console, were you are running your server. @Dev9977

Comment: Sorry i'm getting this from the windows PowerShell.. I run the server from here.. In my browser console i got no logs

Comment: yes, using `windows PowerShell` you have to see your logs and errors

Comment: Okok then what i just posted was from windows PowerShell and it is what i get when i press the button to send my post request

Comment: Ok i got  a 403 using your code. NICE!! now i have to solve this but its wonderful!!!

Comment: ok, I updated my answer, In your ajax, add this line: `csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}"` just where I placed, separated by a comma (,) with `newstitle` parameter. The error is because, you need to send your `csrfmiddlewaretoken` once you add it, should it works

Comment: Ok perfect, but i get Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /API/send_news/

Comment: make sure you have `django.core.context_processors.csrf` in your `CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Comment: Add it in your `settings.py` file, in the `TEMPLATES` category add: `django.core.context_processors.csrf`

Comment: Just done but : ModuleNotFoundError at /API/invia_news
No module named 'django.core.context_processors'

Comment: @Dev9977 what about `'django.template.context_processors.request' ?

Comment: Remove `django.core.context_processors.csrf` and keep `django.template.context_processors.request`

Comment: Still the same problem.. But if i use : csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(), i get a new error (i update my post)